# Swift file converted to almost unreadable code?

Tags: swift, xcode, encoding

Originally, I had a swift file that had a table view. Somehow, the file's name became red and it was missing from the designated path. When I went to the trash, I found the file except the code looked like this:

```
    R®P°"Hfê»êQ@
Ä@,p≠Å(setNumberViewControllerc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController<Ä@“‘UIViewControllerc:objc(cs)UIViewController¥P ∞T¶∞init(nibName:bundle:)c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)initWithNibName:bundle:¥PTu†
init(nibName:bundle:)c:objc(cs)UIViewController(im)initWithNibName:bundle:¥P ∞0}ê
init(coder:)c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)initWithCoder:¥P0lÄinit(coder:)c:objc(cs)UIViewController(im)initWithCoder:ÑaPa6Hz¿
getter:phoneNumberc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)phoneNumberúP· A,zP
phoneNumberc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(py)phoneNumberÑÅP!4H~setter:phoneNumberc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)setPhoneNumber:<Ä@ÄÇRPhoneNumberTextFieldc:@M@PhoneNumberKit@objc(cs)PhoneNumberTextFieldÑaPa6Dy†
getter:backButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)backButtonúP· A(y0
backButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(py)backButtonÑÅP!4D}‡
setter:backButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)setBackButton:<Ä@¿Ä,UIViewc:objc(cs)UIViewÑaPa6Dy†
getter:nextButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)nextButtonúP· A(y0
nextButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(py)nextButtonÑÅP!4D}‡
setter:nextButtonc:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)setNextButton:ÑP §ê4zp
viewDidLoad()c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)viewDidLoadÑP@4i`viewDidLoad()c:objc(cs)UIViewController(im)viewDidLoadÑÅP@@p
setter:maxDigitss:14PhoneNumberKit0aB9TextFieldC9maxDigitsSiSgvsúP@$pêmaxDigitss:14PhoneNumberKit0aB9TextFieldC9maxDigitsSiSgvpÑP §êd¶didReceiveMemoryWarning()c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)didReceiveMemoryWarningÑP@du‡
didReceiveMemoryWarning()c:objc(cs)UIViewController(im)didReceiveMemoryWarning<ÄÄ¿;UITapGestureRecognizerc:objc(cs)UITapGestureRecognizer¥P@Pw∞
init(target:action:)c:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizer(im)initWithTarget:action:ÑP`$ë(v
goBack(_:)c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)goBack:ÑÅP@ly@setter:cancelsTouchesInViewc:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizer(im)setCancelsTouchesInView:<Ä@`Í‡UIGestureRecognizerc:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizerúP@Puê
cancelsTouchesInViewc:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizer(py)cancelsTouchesInViewÑÅP@|n–
setter:isUserInteractionEnabledc:objc(cs)UIView(im)setUserInteractionEnabled:úP@`j 
isUserInteractionEnabledc:objc(cs)UIView(py)userInteractionEnabledÑP@`i
addGestureRecognizer(_:)c:objc(cs)UIView(im)addGestureRecognizer:ÑP`$ë t¿next(_:)c:@M@Reveal@objc(cs)setNumberViewController(im)next:dÉ@ÅA†°Öpgetter:senders:6Reveal23setNumberViewControllerC6goBackySo22UITapGestureRecognizerCF6senderL_AFvgÃP( A¥†senders:6Reveal23setNumberViewControllerC6goBackySo22UITapGestureRecognizerCF6senderL_AFvpdÑ@ÅA†°Öpsetter:senders
```

Is this the same file? Is there any way to go revert back to the original code?

Comment: Restore file from earlier git commit.

Comment: @matt I tried to but apparently did not commit properly for those files ...

Comment: it looks you computer is infected with some kind of viruses and that virus encrypted your file.  Can you please send us this file ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan  I think it has something to do with gitkraken. I think I reverted the files to a stage that didn’t have the new files and thus I lost the uncommitted files, and the files left are from the derived data...

Comment: okay give me some minutes

Comment: decrypting your above data with AES may help you to get your code string

Comment: i haven not found any help other than this :p